# Catching output from ogr2ogr

Tags: ogr2ogr

How do I get the output messages from ogr2ogr, when I call it from another windows application?

I have tried with standard "ogr2ogr.exe>log.txt", but it keeps writing to the console.

Comment: Do you call it from a batch file or how?

Comment: try piping the error output stream too `ogr2ogr.exe>log.txt  2>&1`

Comment: The part with 2>&1 helped, thanks. Never seen that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two output streams for a console. 1 is the standard output and 2 is the error output stream. When you do `my.exe > myfile.txt` it send the standard output (1) to the file, and keeps the error in the console. You could want to send the errors to a different file, or to the standard output. To do this, you would indicate to send the errors (2) to the standard output stream (1) `my.exe > myfile.txt 2>&1` This old but accurate [doc](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) gives further details.

For the case you reported, the command would be `ogr2ogr.exe>log.txt 2>&1`